# How to insert two values in a many-to-many relationship from a python SQL query?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mariadb

I am trying to insert authors in an authors table to match sources through an association table of author_ids and source_ids in a flask website. I am using mariaDB, therefore I am aiming to have it all in one SQL query. So far I haven't been able to make it work with multiple queries.

Table creation

```
CREATE TABLE test_associate_author (author_id int,source_id int);
CREATE TABLE test_source (source_id int auto_increment primary key, title varchar(30));
CREATE TABLE test_author (author_id int auto_increment primary key, forename varchar(10),surname varchar(10));
```

The long way round with pull variables into python is as below.

```
INSERT INTO author (forename,surname) VALUES ("Bob","Smith");
INSERT INTO source (title) VALUES ("Short Stories");
var a =  (MAX(id) FROM from author;
INSERT INTO author (forename,surname) VALUES ("Jackie","Smith");
var b = select (MAX(id) FROM from author;
var c = SELECT (MAX(id) FROM source)
INSERT INTO associate_author (author_id,source_id) VALUES 
(a, c);
INSERT INTO associate_author (author_id,source_id) VALUES 
(b, c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For MariaDB only:**

Keep it simple and avoid additional selects, triggers and other overhead. Especially `SELECT max(id)` might give you an invalid result, since another connection could have inserted and committed another row between.

Instead use RETURNING:

```
INSERT INTO author (forename,surname) VALUES ("Bob","Smith") RETURNING @a_id:=author_id;
INSERT INTO source (title) VALUES ("Short Stories") RETURNING @s_id:=source_id;
INSERT INTO associate_author (author_id, source_id) VALUES (@a_id, @s_id);
```

Comment: mysql doesn't support returning, only mariadb

Comment: The question is tagged as MariaDB

Comment: And mysql also , so the answer of mine is ok

Comment: @GeorgRichter my database is 10.11.3-MariaDB and I also get NULL returned.

Comment: typo fixed: variables have to be assigned with `:=` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 3):

This is one method, but you need to go for every author make a query in a loop

mysql supports user defined variable that are valid in a session.

This must be done as **MySQL** doesn't support RETURNING

```
CREATE tABLE author (id int auto_increment primary key, forename varchar(10),surname varchar(10))
```

```
CREATE tABLE source (id int auto_increment primary key, title varchar(30))
```

```
CREATE tABLE associate_author (author_id int,source_id int)
```

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO source (title) VALUES ("Short Stories");
SET @title = (select LAST_INSERT_ID() from source);

INSERT INTO author (forename,surname) VALUES ("Bob","Smith");
INSERT INTO associate_author (author_id,source_id)  
SELECT 
  (select LAST_INSERT_ID() id from author LIMIT 1) , @title title;

INSERT INTO author (forename,surname) VALUES ("Jackie", "Brown");
INSERT INTO associate_author (author_id,source_id)  
SELECT 
  (select LAST_INSERT_ID() id from author LIMIT 1) , @title title;
COMMIT;
```

> ```
> Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM associate_author
```

| author_id | source_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8Uo6VD7g)

A more elegant solution would to use triggers, but you need still catch the source id first.

Please observer that dbfiddle desn't need DELIMITER for creating a trigger, so depending on gui you need to add it

```
CREATE tABLE author (id int auto_increment primary key, forename varchar(10),surname varchar(10))
```

```
CREATE tABLE source (id int auto_increment primary key, title varchar(30))
```

```
CREATE tABLE associate_author (author_id int,source_id int)
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_author_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON author FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO associate_author (author_id,source_id)  
SELECT 
  (NEW.id) , @title ;
END
```

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO source (title) VALUES ("Short Stories");
SET @title = (select LAST_INSERT_ID() from source);

INSERT INTO author (forename,surname) VALUES ("Bob","Smith"), ("Jackie", "Brown");

COMMIT;
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM associate_author
```

| author_id | source_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TGNoUlNV)

Comment: this answer is for mysql and not mariadb